# Is there a way to check the SQL generated by ADO.NET methods without resorting DB tracing/profiling?

Tags: .net, ado.net

I want to test that application A (legacy) and application B (current) are sending the same SQL to the database.  Is there an easy way to check the generated SQL?

I'm not too concerned with minor syntax differences.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect tracing is the most robust option. Some things (like LINQ-to-SQL) allow query logging, but certainly not all. But you have more safety that a trace will catch everything.

Note that "minor syntax differences" will make it very painful to compare, of course